# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto Angular con Angular-Cli

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas estoy intentando crear un nuevo proyecto siguiendo el manual de Angular usando Angular-Cli. Tengo instalado Node 6.10.0 y npm 3.10.10 en Windows 10 
primero instalé angular cli con el comando:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli que se completo sin errores
```

pero al ejecutar el comando para crear el proyecto(ng new my-app) recibo el siguiente error:

```
Installing packages for tooling via npm.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--quiet" "install"

npm ERR! node v6.10.0

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! path c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\.staging\rx-59741874

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! syscall rename


npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\.staging\rx-59741874' -> 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\rx'

npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)

npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29

npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\.staging\rx-59741874' -> 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\rx'

npm ERR!     at Error (native)

npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\.staging\rx-59741874' -> 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\rx'

npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)

npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29

npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\.staging\rx-59741874' -> 'c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\node_modules\rx'

npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'my-app' }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     c:\Users\usuario\Documents\workspace\my-app\npm-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

El comando se ha ejecutado en modo administrador, agradeceria mucho si alguien pudiera indicarme que me esta fallando.

Comment: No uso Windows, y no se, si esto solucionara su problema, pero he visto que en errores similares se hablaba del McAfee antivirus, quizas si no encuentra la solucion y usted tiene instalado McAfee, probaria a desinstalarlo  igual le funciona. Saludos

Comment: Puedes subir la version de Angular CLI que estas usando? ng -v

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar la respuesta para el comando ng -v es: `@angular/cli: 1.0.0 node 7.8.0 os: win32 x64` la version de npm es 4.2.0

Comment: Escribo de todas maneras para que lo tengan presente, en el repositorio de angular-cli te indica los pasos que tienes que hacer, en caso se tenga que actualizar angular-cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado, al perecer angular-cli no estaba instalado correctamente desde un inicio, con la instalación de windows-build-tools se ha solucionado el problema esta es la secuencia que he seguido con el antivirus desactivado como dijeron Juan Hernandez y Angel:

Desinstalar Angular Cli
`npm cache clean
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Instalar Windwos Build tools 
`npm cache clean
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Instalar angular cli
`npm cache clean
npm install -g -f @angular/cli`

muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo a los tres.

Comment: Debes dar puntos a las colaboraciones y marcar como solucionada la pregunta.

Comment: realice todos los paso que indicaste, pero sigo con la misma falla, angular damuchos errores

Answer (score 1):

Tienes primero que limpiar el caché con:

```
npm cache clean
```

Después desactiva el antivirus que tengas ya que algunos usuarios han reportado problemas al usar NOD o AV antivirus, y vuelve a crear el proyecto.

```
ng new my-app
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, Uso Windows Defender lo he desactivado y he realizado los pasos de limpiar cahe y crear el proyecto pero  sigue dando el mismo error, voy a probar a desinstalar angular cli y volver a instalarlo con la opcion -f he leido en algunos hilos en ingles que a algunos les ha funcionado

Comment: Bueno pues con la opción -f me ha dado un error la instalación de angular cli, el error es mas largo pero estas lineas `gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb which failed Error: not found: python2` me hacen pensar que posiblemente la solución este en este comando `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` que encontre en este hilo https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2256

Comment: mm eso menciona que hay un problema con python en sí, o no lo tienes o simplemente no lo has agregado a tu path, entonces te recomiendo que primero instales bien python 2.7 y después elimines node y angular-cli para evitar que algún archivo esté corrupto ya que no se ha de haber cargado bien porque no tenías bien configurado python y con eso podrías volver a instalar todo en las últimas versiones.

Comment: @OriolTortosa puedes user los siguientes comandos para desinstalar angular-cli: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`y `npm cache clean`. No olvides quitar node para evitar conflictos.

Comment: @OriolTortosa debes dar puntos a las colaboraciones y marcar como solucionada la pregunta.

Comment: que conste que le he dado a los puntos pero me dice que no se suman por que soy noob :(

Comment: entiendo que aceptando la respuesta queda solucionada la pregunta no?

Comment: @OriolTortosa exacto.

Comment: gracias de nuevo